# applescript to move files in numeric order

Tags: automation, applescript

i started a project for a friend, that involved moving large quantities of files into specific folders. i was using automator as I'm handling the project on my mac, however automator does not have a feature to move section of files that are numbered numerically. for instance i will have files that are say "this file 100" and ill have 100 files like that. and then files that say "That file 50" and ill have 200 files like that. the project is splitting these files into there own folder but in section. so ill need "This file" 1-25 in one folder 26-80 in anther and so on. same is true for the "THAT FILES" but there isn't a pattern just the requirement my friend has asked for.

is there a easy way to write a script that could grab 1-25 or any sequel ordering with the same file name? because moving each file one at a time with automator has been taking to long.

thank you so much in advanced

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure tu fully understand your naming convention, but overall , yes, with Applescript, you can move files into folders based on names, eventually adding sequence numbers.

Because I am not sure about your requirements, at least, here are some sample of syntax for main operations :

Get list of files with names containing xxx in folder myFolder :

```
Tell Application "Finder" to set myList to every file of myFolder whose name contains "xxx"
```

Then you have to do a repeat / end repeat loop :

```
Repeat with aFile in myList
   -- do something here with aFile : example with name of aFile
end repeat
```

In that loop you can extract name, parse it, add a counter,...
To move file to new folder, you must use "move" instruction in a tell "Finder" bloc. Instruction "make" can also be used to create new destination folder based on name or root names of files. You must remember that Applescript commands will give error if same file name already exists in destination folder : Finder is able to add "copy" in the name, but you must do it yourself in Applescript.

Last advice if about the number of files to handle. If that number is not so high (less than few hundreds) Applescript is still OK for speed. If your number of files is much higher, then you must use either shell command or, better, a mix of AS and shell commands. The shell commands can be called from AS with a "do shell script". For instance, getting the list of 1000 files from a folder is time consuming with AS, but much quicker with 'ls' command ! Same for a copy. here is an example of copy using shell 'cp'  :

```
do shell script "cp " & quoted form of (POSIX path of (aFile as string)) & " " & quoted form of (POSIX path of DestFolder) & (quoted form of newFileName)
```

Note : "Posix path" converts the AS file path (Users:myName:Documents:File.txt) into shell path (Users/myName/Documents/File.txt)

I hope it helps.